# How can I alternate the background colors of nested children of the same class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code:

```html
<lib_col class="lib_card">
  <lib_col class="lib_card">
    <lib_col class="lib_card">
      <lib_col class="lib_card">
        <lib_col class="lib_card">
          <!--content -->
        </lib_col>
      </lib_col>
    </lib_col>
  </lib_col>
</lib_col>
```

I want the background color to alternate between them. I tried the following thing:

```css
.lib_dark > .lib_card,
.lib_dark > .lib_card > .lib_card > .lib_card,
.lib_dark > .lib_card > .lib_card > .lib_card > .lib_card > .lib_card {
  background: var(--lib_dark_2);
}
.lib_dark,
.lib_dark > .lib_card > .lib_card,
.lib_dark > .lib_card > .lib_card > .lib_card {
  background: var(--lib_dark);
}
```

There are 2 issues here:

- using `>` operator is not good for the job, since I might have another container in the middle that is not a card, and its purpose is for aligning content, not necessary something visible to the user (no background color)
- it does not go to infinity. the current example will not correctly modify the background color of the 6th card

For clarification, I don't want the first-level children in a parent to alternate, but to alternate between levels. If a parent has 2 children, both of them will have the same color. The children should never have the color of the parent, so the alternating happens hierarchy-wise, unlike the rows of a table.

```css
:root {
  --lib_dark: #ccc;
  --lib_dark_2: #333;
}

.lib_card {padding: 8px}

.lib_dark>.lib_card,
.lib_dark>.lib_card>.lib_card>.lib_card,
.lib_dark>.lib_card>.lib_card>.lib_card>.lib_card>.lib_card {
  background: var(--lib_dark_2);
}

.lib_dark,
.lib_dark>.lib_card>.lib_card,
.lib_dark>.lib_card>.lib_card>.lib_card>.lib_card {
  background: var(--lib_dark);
}
```

```html
<div class="lib_dark">
  <div class="lib_card">
    <div class="lib_card">
      <div class="lib_card">
        <div class="lib_card">
          <div class="lib_card">
            Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the snippet demo above show the problem? It's best if you use actual HTML for HTML questions.

Comment: It does not. It was not added by me, someone edited the question. My original cards uses padding, so the colors are actually visible

Comment: So fix it. I'm that someone, and I'm trying to actually see the problem. You're expected to show it, if possible, and it sure seems possible here.

Comment: See [ask] for tips.

Comment: The code works now. I want to alternate exactly like in the demo, but to cover the 2 issues I told about in the question

Comment: @uIM7AI9S Do you have to nest the divs? Can't you put them adjacent?

Comment: @TermoPollo They must be inside one-another. I won't necessary have large amounts of nesting, but the UI should update their colors if for example, my drag-and-drop code drops the card into a position with different parity

Comment: You could have used [:nth-of-type(odd | even)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). But if you have to nest them, I believe your only alternative is to use JavaScript.

Comment: Showing the desired result is nice, but can you put a example of your edge cases? So we can see where it does not work. That imo would make showing the problem easier.

Comment: I don't think this is possible but here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909765/943435) with alternatives.

Comment: The scenario is an anti pattern. You are hacking css to acheive something time wasteful. If you have to hack it use js to iterate the nest to alternate add a class